# Not possible to connect to the Web3 provider. Make sure the provider is running and a connection is open (via IPC or RPC)

Tags: remix

While trying to connect Ganache-cli to remix, I get this error,

```
Not possible to connect to the Web3 provider. Make sure the provider is running and a connection is open (via IPC or RPC).
```

But remix IDE is able to connect to testRPC and not Ganache-cli, i have both on my system, I tried with both local copy of remix as well with online remix IDE.

Comment: Doesn't work on Brave browser. However it works with Crome browser for both http & https versions of remix.

Answer (score 2):

Run Remix from http://remix.ethereum.org, not **https**

Found the answer here:
[Testrpc running on 8545, yet Remix can't connect](https://github.com/ethereum/remix/issues/588)

Comment: 's answer worked for me. If you are using brave browser then please disable the shield protection and change the `https` to `http` in the address bar

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to an add blocker.  I did not have to do any of the http changes described in the other answers.  I was using Brave Browser and just had to disable the Brave Shields ("Shields Up") and was good to go.